# change data type of a array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have created a array by generating a group of random numbers and converted them into int type. However, i do not think my way below is efficient. Is there a best way to change the data type in a array?

```
# standard normal distributed random numbers
c=random.randn(5,5)
c

array([[-0.37644781, -0.81347483, -0.36895952, -2.68702544, -0.96780752],
   [ 0.05293328,  1.65260753,  0.55586611, -0.5786392 ,  0.50865003],
   [ 1.25508358,  0.51783276,  2.36435212, -0.23484705, -1.20999296],
   [ 2.07552172,  0.65506648,  0.10231436, -0.26046045,  0.40148111],
   [ 0.24864496, -1.8852587 , -2.51091886,  1.01106003,  1.53118353]])

d=array([[-0.37644781, -0.81347483, -0.36895952, -2.68702544, -0.96780752],
       [ 0.05293328,  1.65260753,  0.55586611, -0.5786392 ,  0.50865003],
       [ 1.25508358,  0.51783276,  2.36435212, -0.23484705, -1.20999296],
       [ 2.07552172,  0.65506648,  0.10231436, -0.26046045,  0.40148111],
       [ 0.24864496, -1.8852587 , -2.51091886,  1.01106003,  1.53118353]],dtype=int)

d
array([[ 0,  0,  0, -2,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  2,  0, -1],
       [ 2,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, -1, -2,  1,  1]])
```

Comment: Do you need them normally distributed? If not, `np.random.random_integers(-2, 2, (5, 5))` or similar might do it.

Comment: I understand what you say, but my object is to create a array by using any  way and change the data type in the array to another type,such as from int to float or from int to complex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either you find a way to get the output with the correct type or you use `astype`, see the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html), in order to change the type of an array

In your case the following example gives you an array of type `np.int`

```
c=random.randn(5,5).astype(np.int)
```

Comment: Would this actually be more efficient? It performs the same steps, creating a float array then converting it to integer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : I don't think so ... but you avoid copying the output into a new array by hand

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Even though the OP asked for "efficient", I suspect he doesn't really mean "efficient". You really think the cost of copying-and-casting a 5x5 NumPy array is a bottleneck in his program? Or that he finds manually printing out an array, copying and pasting and editing it is an inefficient way to code?

Comment: @abarnert frankly, I assumed that: 1. they meant what they said; and 2. this was just a small example to show the process. Who knows, though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I've gotten used to novices using the word "efficient" to mean… well, I'm never sure what, it's always vague, but "fast enough performance for my use case" or "algorithmically optimal performance" or anything remotely similar is rarely even close to whatever they're after…

Answer (score 2):

Also: `np.cast[int](c)`, which doesn't presume it's argument is a NumPy array.